# How to filter seven days last Flatlist React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to filter seven days last, I am using Flatlist to render these items.

[image]

Comment: You should provide your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a simple version of what you want:

```
const sevenDaysAgo = Date.now() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1000 // seven days ago in timestamp
const [data, setData] = useState(your Data);
const sevenLastDaysData = useMemo(() => {
    return data.filter(item => item.date >= sevenDaysAgo);
    // IMPORTANT: item.date Must be timpestamp other wise you should convert it to timestamp  
}, [data]);

return (
   <FlatList
       data={sevenLastDaysData}
       ...
   />
```

)